# Why is a method passed through props being used also when it shouldn't (react)

Tags: reactjs

I am passing a method through props

```
export default class Layout extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      className: 'container tray'
    }
  }
  handleClick(){
    this.setState({
      className: this.state.className === 'container' ? 'container tray' : 'container'
    })
  }
  render() {
     <Sidebar handleClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} />
  }
}
```

Then I want to be able to trigger it only when clicking on one element

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {Link} from 'gatsby'
export default class Sidebar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="sidebar">
        <div className="links">
            <ul>
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
            <li onClick={this.props.handleClick} >tags</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

When I click on `tags` it should trigger `handleClick` which it does, but it sometimes also gets triggered when I click on other links

(this is a gatsby project, those links go to different pages)

Edit: If I remove the `Link` the unusual behavior doesn't happen

Comment: Please, provide a demo to replicate the problem. I see no reasons why it *gets triggered when I click on other links* from the code that was posted.

Comment: Also please comment on the expected behavior. It looks to me as though you've designed this to toggle the 'tags' `<li>` between `className` 'container' and 'container tray'. Is that right? Do you mean that when you click on other parts of the page, that same `<li>` toggles class even though you didn't click on it?

Comment: @AndyTaton that's right. The problem is that the behavior I expect when clicking `<li onClick={this.props.handleClick} >tags</li>` I also get when clicking `<li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>`. @estus, I see no reason either, I replicated it in a fresh react setup and work fine but on my project it doesn't, I thought you might have some pointers

Comment: @relidon your last line is why no one is going to be able to help you given the code you supplied.  The pointers is debug your code and trace the stack.  Make sure you've properly closed off your elements (`div`s, `li`s, `ul`s) and aren't passing `handleClick` to other elements

Comment: This is not a solution to your issue but regarding function binding. You are directly binding handler function in render, never do that instead always bind it in constructor. The only place for binding is constructor and never do binding anywhere in the component

Comment: I do tested your code in my local and the onlick is working only when clicking tags. Your code is absolutely right. You must be doing something else in your code or maybe you are in that assumption

Comment: @Think-Twice Strange, I know it's right, but I just reinstalled gatsby again, added the same code and get the same problem. I've done this many times in react apps and the behavior I expect is the right one. I just don't know why I'm getting the error

Comment: @relidon can you put the code in sandbox so that it's easy for us to identify the issue rather putting our heads here with an assumption. Is that make sense?

Comment: React's `className` property can also accept an array, and I've seen posts before where authors propose this as a solution to component styling library issues. (I know, that might not be what you have here, but bear with me.) What happens if you replace `'container tray'` with `['container', 'tray']`?

Answer (score 0):

In your click function, do the following and see if this solves your problem.

```
handleClick(evt){
    evt.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
      className: this.state.className === 'container' ? 'container tray' : 'container'
    })
}
```

Something might be happening as a result of event propagation.